# What's the idiomatic way to avoid wasted renders from defining new objects in render()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `PureComponent` with the following render method:

```
  render() {
    return <div>
      <List items={_.map(this.state.filteredItemIds, id => this.state.items[id])} />
      <SearchBox value={this.state.searchValue} onChange={this.handleSearchChange} />
    </div>;
  }
```

(See [nickheiner/react-demo](https://github.com/NickHeiner/react-demo/blob/master/src/App.js) for the full source code.)

`List` will re-render every time, because `_.map` will always return a new array. The shallow equality check in `shouldComponentUpdate()` will always return false.

My goal is to have a state that looks like this:

```
this.state = this.updateFilteredItemIds({
  items: [
    {id: 0, name: 'Apple'},
    {id: 1, name: 'Orange'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Horse'},
  ],
  filteredItemIds: null,
  searchValue: ''
});
```

And when I render `<List>`, I want to pass `items` to be only those items that are selected by `filteredItemIds`. How can I do this without creating a new array instance every time in `render()`? What's the idiomatic way to solve this problem?

Or am I supposed to create a new array instance, but override `shouldComponentUpdate()` to do a deep equality check on `filteredItemIds`?

Comment: the component re-renders every time you change your search term because you are probably setting the state on your onChange handler, not because of the map, the map will affect the re-rendering of the List component. is that the one you want to prevent from re-rendering? if that is the case i guess you could make the case for a shouldComponentUpdate in the list or you could not set the `filteredItemIds ` in your state if the lists are the same.

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't totally clear above -- that `state` is for `List`'s` parent, not `List` itself. The only thing I'm passing to `List` is `items`, and I want to know how I can avoid re-renders when two versions of `items` are deeply not not shallowly equal.

Comment: i believe i answer it here `or you could not set the filteredItemIds in your state if the lists are the same` you are setting the state when the search terms change you can compute the `nextList` and compare it with the current one, if they are the same do not set the state and that will prevent the component from re-rendering. as for, how do you determine if the lists are equal or similar, will depend entirely on your data structure, in this case since you are ids you can do things with _.difference to check equality.